# Scrapy print to json file

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I would like to run a spider against craigslist and save the results to a json file using scrapy. My spider displays the results in the console, but my .json file is empty. The command I am using is:

scrapy runspider detroit.py -o detroit.json

Can someone shed a little light, thanks!

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from craigslist_sample.items import CraigslistSampleItem

class MySpider(BaseSpider):
        name = "craig"
        allowed_domains = ["craigslist.org"]
        start_urls = ["http://detroit.craigslist.org/search/sof"]


        def parse(self, response):
                hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
                titles = hxs.select("//span[@class='pl']")
                for titles in titles:
                        title = titles.select("a/text()").extract()[0]
                        link = titles.select("a/@href").extract()[0]
                        print title, link
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are just *printing the results*. You need to **instantiate items** and return them:

```
def parse(self, response):
    for elm in response.xpath("//span[@class='pl']//a"):
        item = CraigslistSampleItem()
        item["title"] = elm.xpath("text()").extract_first()
        item["link"] = elm.select("href").extract_first()
        yield item
```